# Не могу разобраться с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять, почему регулярка не срабатывает для последней строки?

```
[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]уфа([^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]|$)

Manufacturing
asdasdуфаавпвап     true
!!! ...уфа... !!!!! true
sdf уфа             true
уфа                 false
```

Вот здесь можно потыкать интерактивный вариант: https://regex101.com/r/9fNMkj/1

Comment: Используйте [`'~\bуфа\b~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/jx3sPp/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте последовательность символов `\b`, обозначающих **границу слова**:

```
$str = 'Manufacturing
asdasdуфаавпвап
!!! ...уфа... !!!!!
sdf уфа
уфа';

$patt = '~\bуфа\b~u';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот надо:

```
(^|\s*|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9ёЁ])уфа([^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9ёЁ]|\s+|$)
```

`\s` - пробельный символ

`^` - начало строки

`$` - конец строки

`ёЁ` - не забываем любимую букву

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает для последней строки.

Comment: Мне нельзя вырывать кусок слова, в этом вся суть. Т.е. "кекуфакек" - на это не должна реагировать регуляка.

Comment: `\s*` - неверно, должно быть `\s+`.

Answer (score 1):

Ты уже проверяешь на конец строки, но не проверяшь на начало. Надо так:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я])уфа([^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]|$)
```

Но вообще подозреваю, что правильнее было бы использовать `\b`:

```
\bуфа\b
```